# Authorized Flash Client to Java Server connection

Tags: java, flash, security, facebook, oauth

I'm building a Flash-based Facebook game with a Java backend, and I'm planning to use a RESTful approach to connect the two of them (not a persistent socket connection). I'm using the AS3 library to connect the client to Facebook, so that's where I have my session information stored. However, how do I authorize client connections back to the server? I can't leave the callback URLs open since that'd let people manipulate game state without playing the game. I need to make sure that the calls are coming from a valid client and through a valid session.

At the moment, users have no direct login to the backend server -- it's all handled through the client frontend. Can I pass the Facebook OAuth2 access token to the backend in a way that the backend can verify its validity? Should that be enough to trust a valid frontend connection?

I could do a two legged OAuth signed request or just use a simple shared secret, but the keys would have to be packed in with the flash client, which makes that almost useless for this use case.

Somebody has to have solved this problem, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java as a backend, I would consider using [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/).  It is a great library for doing AMF connections (which are async so fit your non-persistent socket requirement).  If you are using Spring on the backend at all, I'd highly recommend using [Spring-Flex](http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex) as well.  It adds a bunch of goodies that make exposing AMF services a breeze.  Also, it adds hooks to allow 'easy' integration of Spring Security.

For the oAuth stuff, I would move the oAuth portion to the web side instead of the flash client (which I think I understand is what you do now).  This way you can authenticate the web session on the server side and secure the page that contains the .swf.  Then when your user loads the .swf in your code (assuming you're using spring security integrated into BlazeDS) you can call cs.authenticated on your cs:mx.messaging.ChannelSet.  This will work, but may be more reword than you want to do.

Comment: My biggest concern with moving the authentication to the client side is passing the token on to the flash client so that i can make calls from there as well. I'm using Facebook's api, which is based on oauth2. Does spring-flex support that? I've used spring and spring security before, but never spring-flex.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problem in one of our project. What we ended up doing was used the following token passing method:

1) Fresh client connects to the server and get a token that's valid for x amount of time.

2) The client has an obfuscated part of code that uses an algorithm to change the token (and this algorithm changes at some frequency in sync with the server). The client uses the algorithm to change the token and includes it in the next request to the server.

3) The server knows the original token and the algorithm so now it can check to see if the new token in valid and it's from a valid client.

4) The cycle continues.

This is no 100% secure, since someone can really spend time and analyze the communication and eventually understand the pattern, but you can play around with the algorithm so much and change it often enough to make it hard for someone to guess it.

Hope this helps.

P.S. The application that I'm talking about that uses this has been in production for past 5 years and gets ~300k unique users a day and no one has broken in yet.